# I have a list in python which contains many names, I want to print out how many times each name occurs

Tags: python, list, sorting

Ex:

```
list = ['herp' , 'derp', 'foo' , 'derp', 'foo', 'foo' , 'foo']
```

I want to be able to get this code so that I can print out:

```
herp occurs 1 times.
derp occurs 2 times.
foo occurs 4 times.
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: this is a distinct question from counting the occurrences of a single list item, and will have a different answer (the Counter answer is likely to prevail)

Comment: @Sparr: Yet I see `Counter` answers for both of the linked questions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, Counter is very versatile

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [`collections.Counter()` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects):

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(lst)

for word, count in counts.most_common():
    print '{} occurs {} times'.format(word, count)
```

This has the nice side-effect of sorting your words by frequency. If you need the words sorted in alphabetical order, sort the `.items()` result:

```
import operator

for word, count in sorted(counts.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
```

Demos:

```
>>> lst = ['herp' , 'derp', 'foo' , 'derp', 'foo', 'foo' , 'foo']
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counts = Counter(lst)
>>> for word, count in counts.most_common():
...     print '{} occurs {} times'.format(word, count)
... 
foo occurs 4 times
derp occurs 2 times
herp occurs 1 times
>>> import operator
>>> for word, count in sorted(counts.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
...     print '{} occurs {} times'.format(word, count)
... 
herp occurs 1 times
derp occurs 2 times
foo occurs 4 times
```

Comment: OP seems to want `.most_common()[::-1]`

Comment: @jamylak: it more looks like the original order of the input list, but most of all, there probably is no particular order required.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter

Counter(['herp' , 'derp', 'foo' , 'derp', 'foo', 'foo' , 'foo'])
# Counter({'foo': 4, 'derp': 2, 'herp': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Walk through your list and build a dictionary of names, and increment a counter for each dictionary entry for the number of times you've encountered the name.

Comment: What you describe here *is* [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: @InbarRose I know that now. Didn't know it when I answered.

Comment: That is great! Learning new things and improving yourself are core values at StackOverflow. :)